# No longer able to log in to Stack Exchange

Tags: support, login, stackexchange.com

I am suddenly unable to log in to Stack Exchange. I have OpenID set up to use Google's service, and it worked perfectly for years. Now, whenever I try to log in, I see this:

[image]

The only way I was able to get back in was by following an authenticated link from one of the Stack Exchange emails (I generally frown when I see authenticated links in emails, but this time they saved my bacon :) ). Going into my profile, I see the correct Gmail account, and I was even able to add a secondary one:

[image]

However, if I try to log back in, I still get the "new to Stack Exchange" message.

I also tried using password recovery - but that is also impossible, even though I'm using the same email:

[image]

Why does this happen, and what I can do to log in "normally" once again?

Comment: This error appears to be in stackexchange.com, what you get when trying to login in other sites?

Comment: It seems like you manually set up your account using Google's OpenID endpoint. Google retired their OpenID endpoint a long time ago; current SE accounts linked to Google accounts are authenticated in a different manner now.

Comment: @Sonic - I just set up a new authentication with a second Gmail account. So even if the old one has since become invalid, this new one should work, right? But it doesn't... Also, notice that they both show up as being "successfully used" a few minutes ago - the login works, it's just StackExchange not recognizing the association between the login and an existing account.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - What do you mean by "other sites"? I can log in to Gmail with no problem, and I don't have that particular OpenID configured anywhere else except StackExchange.

Comment: For example [this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). Are you logged in there fine?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Indeed, that seems to be specific to the ("root"?) stackexchange site. If I go to a subdomain (such as scifi.stackexchange.com ), my login works. I guess my mistake was trying to login directly to the "main" stackexchange.com site?

Comment: Yeah, stackexchange.com (which is known as the "portal" to Stack Exchange) has some weird problems since it's running on different code base. Your exact issue was reported before though, there is one possible solution already, give this a try and see if it helps you too. :)

Comment: Indeed - sorry for the duplicate. I don't know how that question didn't pop up when searching :( . Thank you for your help!

Comment: @PeterMortensen Every time you edit a closed question within five days of closure, three other users need to dismiss the resulting reopen review queue item as "Leave Closed". This also deprives the post author of their chance to get their question reopened. Please consider this before editing closed posts within five days of them being closed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It would be very nice if you joined me in chat: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1176/sonics-den